# EXcel Macro Doesn't Return SQL

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am trying to write an excel macro that will return results from a SQL database. The macro asks for user input, formats it, and inserts it into the query. Somewhere in there is the problem- I get an error saying no rows were found, but when I run the query in SQL (with formatted number) it executes properly.Can someone tell me what is wrong?

I am guessing that my syntax is wrong, and SQL is interpreting ' & PID1 ' as text rather than a variable.

```vb
Sub SQLExcelCon()

    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sConnString As String
    Dim PID_Raw As String
    Create the connection string.
    sConnString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;" & _
    "server=pasql1\internal;database=Vision;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

    ' Create the Connection and Recordset objects.'
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    ' Open the connection and execute.'
    conn.Open sConnString

    ' Ask for user input and fromat it for SQL '
    PID_Raw = InputBox(prompt:="enter parcel id")
    PID1 = Left(PID_Raw, 2) & "-" & Mid(PID_Raw, 3, 2) & "-" & Mid(PID_Raw, 5, 2) & "-" & Mid(PID_Raw, 7, 4) & "-" & Mid(PID_Raw, 11, 5) & "-" & Mid(PID_Raw, 16, 4)

    ' Execute query '
    Set rs = conn.Execute("select REM_ACCT_NUM from REALMAST where REM_ACCT_NUM like ' " & PID1 & "'")
    MsgBox ("select REM_ACCT_NUM from REALMAST where REM_ACCT_NUM like " & PID1)

    ' Check we have data. '
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        ' Transfer result. '
        Sheets(1).Range("B3").Value = "PARCEL ID"
        Sheets(1).Range("B4").CopyFromRecordset rs

        ' Close the recordset '
        rs.Close

    Else
        MsgBox "Error: No records returned.", vbCritical
    End If

    Sheets(1).Range("C20").Value = PID1

    ' Clean up '
    If CBool(conn.State And adStateOpen) Then conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

The user wants to write a number such as 1125200020000000170. The query should return 11-25-20-0020-00000-0170 if it is in the database. Instead it says "No records returned."

Comment: try removing the space after the '. Set rs = conn.Execute("select REM_ACCT_NUM from REALMAST where REM_ACCT_NUM like '" & PID1 & "'")

Comment: @h2so4 Ok, that worked - I posted an answer before I read your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed it -

Set rs = conn.Execute("select REM_ACCT_NUM from REALMAST where cast(REM_ACCT_NUM as text) like '" & PID1 & "'")